# How put two p element next to each other

Tags: html, css, web

How can i put two p elements next to each other,

Using inline method every line in p element gets serrated so what is the correct way? 
"i can't find any question on it"
here is my code on this

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.div1 {
  width: 100%
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.p1 {
  width: 50%;
  background: rgb(136, 224, 220);
}

.p2 {
  width: 50%;
  background: rgb(114, 235, 131);
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <p class="p1">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p class="p2">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
```

here the answer

```
p {
  margin: 0;
  display:inline;
  float:left;
 }
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kartik_me/Lqf5duw6/

Comment: for some reason i cant put link in question so here it is

Comment: The reason is told in the [help] - we want code HERE

Comment: lol why -1 vote

Comment: Because there was no code until Turnip fixed it for you

Comment: ok but now it should be gone i was also trying to to put code or link but it was not working

Comment: The whole point of a p tag is to be on separate lines... the p means paragraph. Using divs or spans is a better way.

Comment: @Studocwho thx your comment make sense and its working

Answer (score 4):

Change `display` in css or play with different elements like `span`.

```css
.Same{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p class='Same'>Good</p>
<p class='Same'>Bad</p>
```

Comment: not working, no change in result

Comment: make both `p1` and `p2` `inline-block` and apply width less than `50%` like `calc(50% - 2px)` may be because of margin and padding in parents...